# Get Android data usage before device boot

Tags: android

For the application I'm working on, I would like to be able to calculate how much mobile data the user has used on their phone over the past few months. We have been using [TrafficStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html), but as it clearly says in the documentation it will only provide information since the phone has been turned on. E.g.:

> **getMobileRxPackets()**
>
> Return number of packets received across mobile networks since device
>   boot.

Is there any way of getting this information before a phone has been turned off? I would have thought this information would be available somewhere, especially since I can see it myself on my own phone (pictured here data usage information from several months ago):

[image]

Comment: Does this Data Usage screen provide a content provider? If so, you can read the data from there. Otherwise, you will have to run a service, tracking data sent through TrafficStats and store it in a database, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Rogier. What do you mean by "content provider"? This screen is built into Android (I access it by going into Settings > Data Usage on Android 4.4.4).

Comment: Content providers (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) provide access to data they keep for you. For example, the Contacts content provider (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html) provides access to all stored contacts. Maybe the Data Usage screen also provides a content provider, allowing you to read the data.

Comment: @RogiervanhetSchip Thanks, seems like it doesn't provide a Content Provider. Either that or I can't find it anywhere.